# How to send correct http response from python?

Tags: javascript, python, networking

I have an index.html file, which has some javascript in it. The script is basicly creating a WebSocket. I want it to connect to a server which has a python script running, to send and HTTP response for the to communicate. I'm not sure if this is even possible, im quite new in networking so im still learning

Javascript:

```
    function getData(){
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws:my server's ip:6474");
        socket.onopen = () => socket.send("Hello, world!");
    }
```

Python:

```
import socket

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
serverSock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 6474))
serverSock.listen(1)

while True:
     sock, addr = serverSock.accept()
     sock.send('HTTP/1.1\nContent-Type: text/html\n')
     data = sock.recv(1024)
     print(data.decode('utf-8').rstrip())
```

The reason I dont have '200 OK' is because that gives an error.

The getData() gets called whenewer a button is pressed in html. That works correctly. I get no errors but I don't see any text appearing on the server. (except the html from the .js file)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but after header there must be a blank line

```
sock.send('HTTP/1.1\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
```